# How to Get IDENT_CURRENT result with c# ' s SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which I want to get the last inserted row for a specific table say table `TbUsers` , so in the end of it, I type that line:

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('TbUsers')
```

Now I want to get that result in C#, using `SqlCommand`; I pass these parameters to to the stored procedure:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertUsers", conn);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

/* Insert in TbUsager */
SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
           new SqlParameter("@firstName" ,value.firstname),
           new SqlParameter("@lastName",value.lastname),
           new SqlParameter("@email",value.email),
           new SqlParameter("@phoneNumber",value.phoneNumber),
           new SqlParameter("@address",value.address),
           new SqlParameter("@country",value.country),
           new SqlParameter("@city",value.city),
           new SqlParameter("@zipCode",value.zip_code)
        };
command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

var rdr = command.ExecuteReader()
```

How can I get the returned result of the stored procedure?

## Update

i have added this code :

```
  // command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        var LastInsertedUsagerId = new SqlParameter("@lastInsertedUsagerId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        LastInsertedUsagerId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add(LastInsertedUsagerId);

    //    var rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        var LastInsertedUsagerId2 = command.Parameters["@LastInsertedUsagerId"].Value;
```

but i still getting null as a result ?

## Update2

this is my SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUsager]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Nom_Usager varchar(20),
@Prenom_Usager varchar(20),
@Email_Usager varchar(20),
@Telephone_Portable_Usager  varchar(20),
@Adresse_Usager varchar(20),
@Pays_Usager varchar(20),
@Ville_Usager varchar(20),
@IdVille_Usager varchar(20),
@LastInserted_IdUsager int OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN


-- Insert a new usager 

declare @IdinsertedUsager table(IdinsertedUsager int)
declare @IdAddressVillePayselse table(IdAddressVillePayselse int)
declare @newUsager int , @IdAddressVillePays int , @addressvp int,@IdCountry int,@IdVille int



Insert into TbUsager (IdTypeUsager,Nom_Usager,Prenom_Usager,Indic_Maj)
Output inserted.IdUsager into @IdinsertedUsager
values(1,@Prenom_Usager,@Nom_Usager,'P')

SELECT @newUsager = IdinsertedUsager FROM @IdinsertedUsager
/* some code */
select @LastInserted_IdUsager=IDENT_CURRENT('TbUsers')
  END
```

and it works well when i execute it in sqlserver

Comment: Use Output variable in SP

Comment: @sriharsha is that necessary ?

Comment: Yes. Approach in that way. You will get that value in C#

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current)

Comment: You can not take the last inserted for a specific table. `IDENT_CURRENT` will return last inserted id from last executed insert statement.

Comment: @Ajay2707 That's actually incorrect. `IDENT_CURRENT` will return the last identity value inserted into a specific table (and as Aaron shows in his article I've linked to above - it sometimes gets the wrong results). What you're referring to might be either `@@Identity` or `scope_identity()`. Read more about it on my blog post entitled [Use the right tool to get identity values back after an insert](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/use-the-right-tool-to-get-identity-values-back-after-an-insert/)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the stored procedure code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, in addition to @Siavash is answer , in order to work we need to use :             ***command.ExecuteNonQuery()***
instead of ***command.ExecuteReader()***

[In this documentation](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-executereader-executenonquery.htm) we get the difference and when to use each one.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're returning the identity id correctly(as output parameter) in your SP, in your C# code you can retrieve it like this:

```
var id = command.Parameters["@id"].Value;
```

Change `@id` to the name of your output variable in SP.
Here's a link to see how to do it correctly in detail:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Identity-value-from-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: i added that but i am getting null !?